# Oracle ADF View Object Expert Mode setWhereClause can't execute parameter from wrapped query

Tags: where-clause, oracle-adf

I have a query which is expert mode query. Also I have viewCriteria and whereClause.

When I use whereClause like under and execute; viewObject can't take any row from database. But when I put the same query in toad, i can see the result. Can you help me...

viewObject getQuery result

```
SELECT   *
  FROM   (SELECT   CO.CUST_ORD_ID,
                   PA.ACTORID_ AS WRK_GRP_ID,
                   CO.CUST_ID,
                   cam_pkg.getCustomerFullName (CO.CUST_ID) AS CUST_NAME,
                   WG.NAME AS WRK_GRP_NAME,
                   TI.CREATE_ AS ACTOIN_DATE,
                   WT.WFLW_TASK_ID,
                   WT.NAME AS WFLW_TASK_NAME,
                   TI.NAME_ AS TASK_SHRT_CODE,
                   CO.ORD_ST_ID,
                   ORS.NAME AS ORD_ST_NAME,
                   TI.PROCINST_ AS PROC_INSC_ID,
                   TI.ID_ AS TASK_ID
            FROM   cust_ord co,
                   JBPM_TASKINSTANCE TI,
                   jbpm_pooledactor PA,
                   jbpm_taskactorpool TAP,
                   wrk_grp WG,
                   ord_st ORS,
                   WFLW_TASK wt
           WHERE   CO.CUST_ORD_ID =
                      jbpm_pkg.get_subLong_jbpm_var_insc (TI.PROCINST_,
                                                          'CustOrderId')
                   AND TI.ISOPEN_ = 1
                   AND TI.END_ IS NULL) QRSLT
 WHERE   (TASK_ID IN
                (1128732,
                 1129513))
```

Answer (score 0):

which version of jdeveloper? and how exactly are you applying the view criteria?  Are you sure you query is getting formed as you are expecting? Try to enable logging by putting 
-Djbo.debugoutput=console in the run/debug properties of your view control project (make sure to bounce the server)